# problem on mantis ticket

Tags: mantis

I want to make ticket number fixed for the different enterprise that can be easy to look at.

The problem I'm facing is when you try to sort the ticket Ids for one enterprise you will find different ticket number so I went to make sequence no arrangement.

eg: I want to adjust the ticket number from (1-1000) to one of my enterprise and (1000-2000) to other one is this possible on mantis ticket.

Comment: Can you give an example? Your question is difficult to understand the way you have written it.

Comment: Is this about the Mantis bug tracker from http://www.mantisbt.org ?

Answer (score 1):

*If* this is about the MantisBT bug tracker, you can't partition by ids. I suggest you create different projects for each enterprise if you don't want them to be mixed.

If you need them in the same project, then use different categories and sort the issues by category.